# PHP Argument Using T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Tags: php, arguments, parameter-passing

I do not want to reinvent the wheel and am aware of other techniques to achieve similar results, but, is it possible to adopt the '=>' operator (used in arrays and foreach loops) as arguments in my own functions/methods?

For example:

```
<?php

function foo($var) {
    var_dump($var);
}

foo('key' => 'value');
```

The above code throws:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in *filename* on line 7
```

I feel by using such an operator in a complex project that obeys to [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) standards would aid in keeping methods within 20 lines and look easier on the eye.

Since Google seems to ignore "=>" at first and all terminologies point to array documentations instead, am I right to assume that this is not possible?

Comment: Do you want to pass an array as argument?

Comment: If you want to follow strict coding standards, why would you want to redefine standards? That is a contradiction. Don't redefine standards (you shouldn't, and in this case I'm pretty sure you can't), use what is available.

Comment: Redefining standards is obviously bad practice.  I was hoping that I overlooked an already standard way to override operators in a manner similar to C++.  The answer below is awesome BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'key' => 'value'` is array syntax so use it in an array:

```
foo(['key' => 'value']);
//or
foo(array('key' => 'value'));
```

Comment: I was doing the latter.  Using [ and ] looks tidy so thanks for the suggestion.